# Kockout.JS ASP.NET MVC loading database values into observales

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I asked a question similar to this recently but I thought I would ask it with a lot more detail to see if someone can explain how this work as I can't seem to find any good documentation on how this works.

I have aASP.NET MVC 6 web app with a following simplified view model.

```
public class ExpenseVm
{
public int ExpenseId { get; set;}
public int Quantity { get; set; }

public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
public decimal TotalCost { get; set; }
}
```

The total cost field is a field calculated in the database.  So I just need to use knockout.JS to update the field realtime for the user on the client.
This works fine when I am trying to create a new expense record using computed observables.

On my  view screen to create a new record I can use the following code and it works fine.

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Quantity" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                 <kendo-numerictextbox name="Quantity" min="0" enable="true" 
         placeholder ="Enter Numeric Value" data-bind="value: Quant" >
                        </kendo-numerictextbox>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UnitPrice" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <kendo-numerictextbox name="UnitPrice" min="0" enable="true" 
            placeholder="Enter Numeric Value" data-bind="value: UPrice">
                    </kendo-numerictextbox>
                    <span asp-validation-for="UnitPrice" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TotalCost" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <span data-bind="text: TotalCost"> </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
```

Knockout code looks like this and this code works fine for my needs

```
    var ViewModel = function (Quantity, UnitPrice) {
        this.Quant = ko.observable(Quantity);
        this.UPrice = ko.observable(UnitPrice);

        this.TotalCost = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            if (isNaN(  this.Quant() * this.UPrice() )) {
                return 0;
            }
            return this.Quant() * this.UPrice();
        }, this);
    };


    ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

However I can’t get seem to pass my values stored in the database to the quantity and unit price fields when I try to implement my edit screen.  If I try to use the same code I used from my create screen I just get blank values for quanity and unitprice.

So I tried pulling some data using using AJAX.  Right now however on my edit screen I don’t seem to able to implement it correctly to pull the JSON data that I need.  I am trying something like this but it doesn’t seem I am able to get any JSON returned.  I am sure I am messing up either the way I am calling  $.getJSON, or doing something wrong in one of my controllers.
Here is my current edit view code.

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="ExpenseId" />
<tr>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Quantity" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <kendo-numerictextbox name="Quantity" min="0" enable="true" 
data-bind="value: Quant">
                    </kendo-numerictextbox>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UnitPrice" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <kendo-numerictextbox name="UnitPrice" min="0" enable="true" 
data-bind="value: UPrice">
                    </kendo-numerictextbox>
                    <span asp-validation-for="UnitPrice" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TotalCost" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <span data-bind="text: TotalCost"> </span>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </td>
```

Here is my attempt at revised Jquery / knockout.js

```
    var Id = $(this).children('#ExpenseId').val();
    $.getJSON("/Expenses/GetQuantity", { id: Id },
        function (data) {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
                // Update view model properties
        var quantity = parsed.Quantity;
        var unitprice = parsed.UnitPrice;

        var ViewModel = function (quantity, unitPrice) {
            this.Quant = ko.observable(quantity);
            this.UPrice = ko.observable(unitPrice);


            this.TotalCost = ko.Computed(function () {
                if (isNaN(this.Quant() * this.UPrice())) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return this.Quant() * this.UPrice();
            }, this);
        };


        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(quantity, unitprice));
    });
</script>
```

Here are my three controller Actions

```
Create record view – this works fine
public ActionResult CreateExpense()
    {

        return View(vm);

    }
```

Standard Edit record controller – populates initial values of quantity and unit cost that are stored in the database.  This Works fine before trying to add Knockout.js.  After adding my knockout the fields of quantity and unit price still populate on the view but fields don’t seem to bind to knockout viewmodel.

```
    public IActionResult EditExpense(int? id) 
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var vm = new ExpenseVm();
        Expense expense = _context.Expenses.Single(m => m.ExpenseId == id);

        if (expense == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        vm.Quantity = expense.Quantity;
        vm.UnitPrice = expense.UnitPrice;
        vm.StaffLevelId = expense.StaffLevelId;            
        vm.TotalCost = expense.TotalCost;
        return View(vm);
    }
```

Action to return json for the two fields – (I think this may be where I am getting messed up.)

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Produces("application/json")]

    public ActionResult GetQuantity(int? id)
    {
        Expense expense = _context.Expenses.Single(m => m.ExpenseId == id);

        return Json(expense);
    }
```

Questions I would like to ask that I  think would assist me to figure this out.

1. Is there a way to have the quantity and unit price fields pull the data from the database using my ASP.net viewmodel but also make the fields observables without having to use AJAX.
2. If not how do I load my initial view model on the screen that contains many other fields, and then just load the quantity and unit price using AJAX and then also bind those fields as observables.
   Since I am pretty new to JQuery, AJAX, and Knockout I could really use some pretty in depth help.

Comment: Can you make a simpler example?? That's way too much to test...

Comment: Well basically I just need to know how to seed two observables with values from my asp.net viewmodel but then be able to change the values and have a computed observable update.   The trouble I am having is getting my values from the server into the knockout.JS viewmodel but then having the observables do their updating job on the client.

Comment: I several questions.. maybe not all the code is necessary and you can simplify the example. Have you debugged your code with some JS inspector in the client? Are you returning the values in your Controller? Does your ajax call return expected values in the success function?

Comment: My guess is that your `ViewModel` ko _object_ does not actually `return this;` at any point... but without testing it in a real environment or without debugging info I cannot help you further